# Should OCR be processed on client or on server side?

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying build an Android app which should be able to take a picture of a figure. The figure in this picture should be extracted with OCR and stored on a web service. Would it be better to do the OCR-processing on the client or on the server side?

In my opinion the advantages for the client OCR-processing outweigh the advantages of the server side processing.

Advantages of client-side OCR:

- Minimum data traffic
- Works offline
- Faster

Can you give me any suggestions on whether the client or server-side processing is better or any points I am missing?

Comment: If you have a small number of users, then I guess you could go either way.  If the traffic will be heavy, would you rather scale your servers to many processors (like Google), or harness each user's phone to do their share of the processing?

Comment: It is just a project which i have to do for college. So i won´t have many users. But my decisions should be based on real assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr

Some pros and cons when using local and remote image elaboration. I suggest to give a try to this project and find out performance. Obviously, web-server is fast and powerfull but forces users to be always on line when using your app, but as I understand your app works on-line, so is it a real problem?

A lot of Google apps, use server power to make computation of picture and voice recordings.

Moving the computation to server also allow you to make improvements to the OCR, so no need to update the app.

Good luck!